# PHP Regular expression for maximum of two special characters in a string

Tags: php, validation

I am validating a text field in PHP in which I allow letters, numbers, dots, dashes, and underscore.  But I want a maximum of two dots and/or two dashes and/or two underscores.  How would I do that?  And if that's not doable, then how would I allow maximum of two of any of the above?

Comment: that would work but I would need three of those.  Was hoping to do it in one regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way.

```
function checkString($string){

    $c1 = substr_count($string, '.');
    $c2 = substr_count($string, '-');
    $c3 = substr_count($string, '_');

    if($c1 <= 2 && $c2 <= 2 && $c3 <= 2){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That would work.  But I was hoping for a one-line regular expression.  May not be possible.

Comment: But what is your reason for wanting a 1 line regular expression?